# How would I clean up flipped images from the SDL_surface for next iteration?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, simulation

I am trying simulate a simple pendulum using SDL library. I need to update the screen with new iterated values and to remove already existing image on the screen. How would I do that?

[image: Screenshot of output]

My code is as follows

```
const double g = 9.81, l = 200.0, h = 0.5, u0 = 0, theta0 = 3.1415/3;
const int xoffset = 350, yoffset = 300, r = 10;


//simplified equations 1
double thetadot(double u)
{
    return u;
}

//simplified equations 2
double udot(double theta)
{
    return (-g / l) * sin(theta);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double theta, thetanext, u, unext, ku1, ku2, ku3, ku4, kt1, kt2, kt3, kt4;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
        return 1;

    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 0, SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    if (screen == NULL)
        return 2;
    //putting inital values to the function
    u = u0;
    theta = theta0;

    while(true)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                return 0;
        }

        double x = xoffset + l * sin(theta);
        double y = yoffset + l * cos(theta);

        SDL_LockSurface(screen);

        //string hanging position
        draw_circle(screen, xoffset, yoffset, 10, 0x0000ff00);
        fill_circle(screen, xoffset, yoffset, 10, 0x0000ff00);

        //draw string
        draw_line(screen, xoffset, yoffset, x, y, 0xff3366ff);

        //draw bob's current position
        fill_circle(screen, (int)x, (int)y, r, 0xff004400);
        draw_circle(screen, (int)x, (int)y, r, 0xff3366ff);

        SDL_Delay(150);
        SDL_Flip(screen);

        //Numerical integration of equation 1
        kt1 = thetadot(u);
        kt2 = thetadot(u + 0.5 * h * kt1);
        kt3 = thetadot(u + 0.5 * h * kt2);
        kt4 = thetadot(u + h * kt3);
        thetanext = theta + (h / 6) * (kt1 + 2 * kt2 + 2 * kt3 + kt4);

        //Numerical integration of equation 2
        ku1 = udot(theta);
        ku2 = udot(theta + 0.5 * h * ku1);
        ku3 = udot(theta + 0.5 * h * ku2);
        ku4 = udot(theta + h * ku3);
        unext = u + (h / 6) * (ku1 + 2 * ku2 + 2 * ku3 + ku4);

        //updating values
        u = unext;
        theta = thetanext;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yikes!         `SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
        SDL_Flip(screen);`

Comment: Does it even works? I mean, not crashes, because in theory it should crash. Anyway, use `SDL_FillRect` at the beginning of frame instead of your incorrect `SDL_FreeSurface` at the end.

Comment: @keltar yup. It does work.

Comment: @noufal You are playing with undefined behaviour.

Comment: It only means that SDL is incredibly foolproof at this one. It doesn't change the fact that it just wrong.

Comment: @keltar Hmm...Thanks. I started using SDL library hardly one week before. I have corrected it. Pls let me know if there any similar mistake?

Comment: @noufal as self said in (removed?) answer, you forgot to unlock screen. That's all for now - don't know what your actual drawing functions do, tho.

Comment: @keltar So I should unlock the screen before return. Is it?

Comment: @noufal right before flip

Comment: @keltar so what is the difference between `unlock`ing and `fee`ing the surface?

Comment: @noufal `unlock` finishes surface's memory mapping. After unlock, there is no guarantee `pixels` field is accessible (unless you lock it again). `free` should actually free memory or other resources used by surface; it appears that SDL ignores this call when used on screen surface (i'm almost sure SDL documentation says that screen must never be `free`'d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try clearing the screen using [SDL_FillRect](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FillRect) prior to drawing on it each frame:

```
int SDL_FillRect(SDL_Surface *dst, SDL_Rect *dstrect, Uint32 color);
```

E.g. you could pass it the params `SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, 0x000000)` to clear the whole screen black.

Comment: The only possible answer. A bit of side-theory, but still i would add this - there is no such a thing as 'clear'. This example fills black. It will start actually matter when e.g. whole screen will be updated at each frame - then filling black will become redundant.